# should my angular2+ component data be an object or an observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, design-patterns, rxjs

Let's say I want to build an angular2+ component that fetches some `thing` form the api, and display its name. 
Thanks to some websocket connection, the `thing` can be updated anytime.

Which one of these two approaches is more idiomatic ?

### First attempt: `thing` as an **object**:

Basically, the component subscribes to a websocket observable, and updates its own `thing` object when necessary. If child-components are used, then we will pass a `Thing` as an input.

```
interface Thing { name: string }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-thing',
  template: '<h1> {{ thing?.name }} </h1>',
})
export class ThingComponent implements OnInit {
  public thing: Thing

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private thingService: ThingService,
  ) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.thingService.get(params.id).subscribe(({thing}) => {
        this.thing = thing
      })
    })

    this.thingService.socketObservable().subscribe(newThing => {
      console.log('Thing has been updated !')
      this.thing = newThing
    })
  }
}
```

### Second attempt: `thing` as a **Subject**:

Instead of having an object`thing: Thing`, we now have `thing: Subject<Thing>` (Not shown here, but I'm using Subject instead of Observable so I can complete it in the `ngOnDestroy` method)

In this version, the template uses the `async` pipe, and child-components will receive an observable instead of an `Thing` object.

```
interface Thing { name: string }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-thing',
  template: '<h1> {{ (thing | async)?.name }} </h1>',
})
export class ThingComponent implements OnInit {
  public thing: Subject<Thing>

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private thingService: ThingService,
  ) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.thing = new Subject<Thing>()

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.thingService.get(params.id).subscribe(({thing}) => {
        this.thing.next(thing)
      })
    })

    this.thingService.socketObservable().subscribe(newThing => {
      console.log('Thing has been updated !')
      this.thing.next(newThing)
    })
  }
}
```

From what I can say, both versions *seem* to work. I suspect thtey are not quite equivalent under the hook, but I lack knowledge to decide wether I should prefer the first one or the second one.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you need to use `Subject` because of Socket's "stream" nature. But commonly this question is more related to coding style that you prefer. If you feel yourself comfortable with reactive programming so you probably need to use reactive ways to solve the issues